# What is this bar graph with subgroups called?

Tags: data-visualization, terminology, barplot

Notice that it has groups $(D_1, D_2, D_3)$ and each group has subgroups $(c_1, c_2, c_3)$. [image: poor hand made drawing].

Comment: I think people would call that a grouped bar chart/bar plot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called a [grouped bar chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_chart#Grouped_or_stacked).

There's a list of different types of bar charts [here](http://libweb.surrey.ac.uk/library/skills/Number%20Skills%20Leicester/page_47.htm)

R calls bar charts *barplot*s, and the grouped version is obtained with `beside=TRUE`:[image: grouped bar chart from R]
(example from code in R help on `barplot`)

Excel calls them *clustered column charts* (Excel uses *bar chart* to refer to the version with horizontal bars)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/147786)

Comment: Huh, @lennon310?  The author asks what this is called.  I answered it and told him.  There was no need to obtain any clarification.  it was one of the most straightforward questions asked on CV today.  Simply because the answer isn't paragraphs long doesn't make it inappropriate.

Comment: @Analyst1 Your post is being automatically flagged as low quality and placed in a review queue because it's so short. An autocomment is generated when someone reviews that it's not a good quality answer. Please consider expanding on your answer, perhaps with some additional detail, references and links.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of adding a little detail to your answer. If you wish to go back to your original, click the "edited ... ago"  link at the bottom of your post, scroll down to your original version and click "rollback"

Comment: @StatsStudent Are you and `@Analyst1` the same person?

Answer (score 0):

This is a particular case of what is called a [small multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_multiple). According to Wikipedia, it could also be called **trellis chart**, **lattice chart**, **grid chart**, or **panel chart**. Some software packages like [Vega-Lite](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/) also use the term `facet` to describe its construction.